# How to create jagged arrays which consist of 3 number of arrays (i.e. Arrays of arrays of arrays )?

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration, jagged-arrays, grasshopper

I want to create Boxes in a 3-dimensional grid. To create the same, I stored the number of x,y and z elements in each array and iterated to produce boxes in 3D grid. [C# Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAWE1.png)[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWekb.png)

I expected boxes in a 3D grid [Expected Boxes in 3D grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buE0M.png) But someway I received the error message as mentioned. Could someone please share different ways to script the same?

Comment: Why do you want to store the boxes in a 3D-Grid? Each box should know where it is in the world, so for most use cases it should work fine to generate boxes in a 3D grid, but store them in a regular list.

Comment: Also, [don't post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Is there a question here?